# Why doesn't this readlines () & for iteration work?

Tags: python, text-files

This `readlines ()` function doesn't seem to work and the `for` iteration doesn't either. Also, when I try to write to the file using `file.write ()` it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this is?

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

file = ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')

def appendA ():

 lines = file.readlines()
 print (lines)

 for line in lines:
    print ('1')

    if crop in line:

        print (crop)
        row = str(a)
        split_2 = a.split (',')
        split_2.append (quantity)

def appendB ():

 print ('3')
 file.write ('\n')
 file.write (crop + ' ')
 file.write (quantity + ' ')


with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:

if crop in open('cropdatabase.txt').read():
    appendA ()
else:
    appendB ()

file.close ()
```

[This is what happens when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbnZ1.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Which error? Are you getting the wrong output? Which output?

Comment: No errors, the file isn't written to as it should be and lines is empty. Also, '1' isn't printed so the code doesn't run past the for iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You're not opening the file. You need to use `open(filename, mode).readlines()`

You're using a context manager and caling the `file` variable. But, you haven't actually passed `file` from the context manager to the function. You should also probably name it something else other than `file` in your `with ...` statement since file is a *built in* keyword.

Comment: But isn't that represented by `file`?

Comment: No, `file` is just a tuple containing the name and the mode you *want* to use to open the file. Those are the arguments to pass to the `open` command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a variable called `file`.  In python 2 this was (more or less) the same as `open`.

Second, don't use global variables, pass as a parameter.

Third, put all your code which is not inside functions together at the end.

`a+` does not do what you think.  When you read the file position is already at end-of-file, so you won't read anything.  The simplest is to read the file twice.  You could manipulate the file position using `seek()` but I doubt it is worth it.

I should add that it is highly unusual to append to the same data file.

The `appendA` function is problematic, and I really don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

I realise that I may have got the flow wrong, in that you only wish to appendB if the crop is not present in the entire file.  For that we would use a dictionary to store the crop names - which is much faster than reading the entire file every time.  I can't put that code in because a) I'm not sure that's what you want, and b) I have no idea what the forma of the input file is.

Let's try to sort this out:

```
def appendA(fo, crop, quantity, line):

    print('1')

    if crop in line:

        print(crop)
        #row = str(a)   <<<<  What is a?
        split_2 = line.split(',')
        split_2.append(quantity)

        # Now what ??

def appendB(fo, crop, quantity):

   print('3')
   fo.write('\n')
   fo.write(crop + ' ')
   fo.write(quantity + ' ')

crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

filename = 'cropdatabase.txt'
# First read the file
with open(filename) as fo:
    lines = fo.readlines()

# Now open for append
with open(filename, 'a') as fo:

     for line in lines:
         print(line)
         if crop in line:
             appendA(fo, crop, quantity, line)
         else:
             appendB(fo, crop, quantity)
```

To be honest I'm not certain I understand what the final result should be, but try this and let me know if I have made incorrect assumptions.